# Is there a better way than using the scrollingParallax plugin to scroll my images on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 34 photos that I would like to scroll slightly faster than the page using javascript and I'm currently using the [scrollingParallax plugin](http://dev.jonraasch.com/scrolling-parallax/docs#.UO39p2_gnlc) to do it. However when I switch to my ipad to view it then it becomes rather sketchy! I wanted to make the site responsive because my mum will only look at it there! I wondered if this jerkiness is caused by my inefficient coding, an old plugin or just me being a prat!

I'm essentially looping into the plugin 34 times and I'm sure that this isn't efficient but having limited time and understanding I thought I'd throw it out to the font of all knowledge stackoverflow!

Here's the loop I'm using:

```
/* Photo sprite alignment and scroll   */
for(var i=0; i<34; i++){
var j = '#photo' + (i+1);
$(j).scrollingParallax({staticSpeed : 2.2,staticScrollLimit : false, loopIt : false});
};
```

The css for a couple of photos:

```
.photos{position: fixed; z-index:-1;}

#photo1{top:900px; left:10px;}
#photo2{top:1100px; right:10px;}
#photo3{top:1300px; left:10px;}
#photo4{top:1500px; right:10px;}
#photo5{top:1700px; left:10px;}
#photo6{top:1900px; right:10px;}
#photo7{top:2100px; left:10px;}
#photo8{top:2300px; right:10px;}
```

The html for some photos:

```
<div class="photos">
<img src="img/1.png" id="photo1">
<img src="img/2.png" id="photo2">
<img src="img/3.png" id="photo3">
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: `$('.photos img').scrollingParallax({staticSpeed : 2.2,staticScrollLimit : false, loopIt : false});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shmiddty helped with a better way to call the function but ultimately iOS just didn't run the jquery scrollingParrallax fast enough and so I ended up hiding the class on iOS.

// Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);

```
function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize > 1250) {
        //if the window is greater than 1250px wide then turn on parallax scrolling..
                    $('.fixedPhotos').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.photos img').removeClass('hidden');
            }else{
                    $('.fixedPhotos').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('.photos img').addClass('hidden');
            }
}
// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```